# Updated Mirror Api .Net (v1.5.0.33-beta) client gave problems

Tags: .net, google-mirror-api, google-glass

Today I updated the mirror api client using nuget package manager using following link.

```
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.mirror.v1
```

After that I rebuilt my project. But it gives me a lot of problems.

I need to clarify what are the new methods for following method. Or are there any reference document that we can use.

```
 Oauth2Service userService = new Oauth2Service(initializer);
 String userId = userService.Userinfo.Get().Fetch().Id;
```

and can we use Excute() method instead of Fetch()?

and also when I run this it gives following error

```
Method 'get_BasePath' in type 'Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2.Oauth2Service' from assembly 'Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2, Version=1.3.0.15233, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation
```

what are the modifications we have to have to apply this upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got that works after big struggle.

First I remove all google api references.

Then I install pre release version of following libs

[image]

After that it gives me some reference errors. So I fixed it using updating dependencies.

This [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347290/webapi-odata-5-0-beta-accessing-globalconfiguration-throws-security-error/18700279#18700279) answer helped me a lot.

replace all `Fetch()` to `Execute()`

Comment: For the Glass team, will the .NET QuickStart app be updated to reflect the changes introduced in the latest API release? Things like Fetch/Execute and the deprecation of IAuthenticator?